# split python dataframe with certain number of observations

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the simple version of data frame that I have:

```
customer_ID value_1 value_2 ....
1            0.5    0.2
1            ...    ...
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
....
```

Suppose I have 1000 unique customers in the above data frame and only want to get a sample of data frame with 100 customers in it. The customer_ID is random, and I don't know who's the 100th customer, which means I cannot just assign customers with customer_ID <= 100 into one data frame. How should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can take all the customers_ids to a list:

unique_ID=df.customer_ID.unique()

2. then choose randomly 100 of them to another list

import random

random_ID = random.sample(unique_ID, 100)

3. and finally filter your dataframe with that list

df[df['customer_ID'].isin(random_ID)]

hope it helps

Comment: There was an error "TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d)." occured on the first step. But after I changed it to list by unique_ID=list(df.customer_ID.unique()), it worked. I didn't know isin() function, and it is very useful. Thanks so much for your help.